# Terraform conditional dynamic block with variable objects

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use a variable list of objects to define the value's type and defaults, and use that in a dynamic block. I know there is an experimental feature, but just wondering how I would do this without the experimental feature?

**variables.rf**

```
variable "identity" {
  type = list(object({
    type = string
    identity_ids = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      type = null
      identity_ids = null
    }
  ]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "azure" {
  # Required
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  kind                = var.kind
  sku_name            = var.sku_name

  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identity
    content {
      type         = identity.value.type
      identity_ids = identity.value.identity_ids
    }
  }
}
```

**Use as a module**

```
module "cognitive_account" {
  source                = "../modules/cognitive-account"
  name                  = "name"
  location              = "Australia East"
  resource_group_name   = module.rg.name
  kind                  = "TextAnalytics"
  sku_name              = "S"
  custom_subdomain_name = "unique-name"


  identity = [{
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }]
}
```

Using that code gives me an error:

```
│ Error: Invalid value for module argument
│
│   on main.tf line 66, in module "cognitive_account":
│   66:   identity = [{
│   67:     type = "SystemAssigned"
│   68:   }]
│
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "identity" defined at .terraform\modules\cognitive_account\variables.tf:123,1-20: element 0:
│ attribute "identity_ids" is required.
```

I am not sure how to deal with omitting `identity_ids` from the object block, I thought the default being `null` would take care of it.

Comment: Dynamic blocks are not experimental. So not sure what do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

@marcin, thanks for the tip, a bit more work was required to get this working:

**variables.tf**

```
variable "identity" {
  type = any
  description = <<EOT
    type = Specifies the type of Managed Service Identity that should be configured on the Cognitive Account. Possible values are SystemAssigned, UserAssigned, SystemAssigned, UserAssigned (to enable both).
    identity_ids = A list of IDs for User Assigned Managed Identity resources to be assigned.
  EOT
  default = null
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "azure" {
  # Required
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  kind                = var.kind
  sku_name            = var.sku_name

  dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.identity == null ? [] : [true]
    content {
      type         = lookup(var.identity, "type", null)
      identity_ids = lookup(var.identity, "identity_ids", null)
    }
  }
}
```

**use the module**

```
module "cognitive_account" {
  source                = "../modules/cognitive-account"
  name                  = "name"
  location              = "Australia East"
  resource_group_name   = module.rg.name
  kind                  = "TextAnalytics"
  sku_name              = "S"
  custom_subdomain_name = "unique-name"

  identity = {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Now the identity block is omitted when not provided, and each object in the identity variable can be used without needing to specify all values.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not because of dynamic blocks, but because your `identity` is:

```
  type = list(object({
    type = string
    identity_ids = list(string)
  }))
```

This means that `identity_ids` is **required**, yet when you are using your module, you are not providing it:

```
  identity = [{
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }]
```

You have to **explicitly provide** the `identity_ids`:

```
  identity = [{
    type = "SystemAssigned"
    identity_ids = ["somevalue1", "somevalue2"]
  }]
```

Comment: Yes I know I have to provide it, is there anything I can do to omit that object without using the experimental feature from https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html#experimental-optional-object-type-attributes?

Comment: @philthy If you don't want it enforced nor use experminetal features, then don't specify your `type` in `identity`.